# Rename multer based on POST params NodeJS

Tags: node.js, image

I am uploading an image using multer in NodeJS. I am also renaming the image using diskStorage as such.

```
var limits = {
    fileSize: 3 * 1024 * 1024
};



    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, './public/uploads/')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
          console.log(file);
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
      }
    })

//POST - Upload Profile Picture
var upload = multer({
    limits: limits,
    storage:storage
}).single('upl')



app.post('/api/updateprofile', function(req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        var id = req.body.id;

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json({
                'response': "Cannot upload profile photo",
                'res': false
            });
            return
        }

        updateprofile.onetimeupdate(id, req.file.filename, function(found) {
            console.log(found);
            res.json(found);
        });
    });
});
```

But I would like to rename the file based on the passed POST param "id". So I would like to say something like,

```
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, req.body.id)
      }
```

but this doesn't work. Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: You are not fetching params in the route and nor you are accessing the value correctly. `req.params.id`

Comment: I tried that too but it didnt work. console.log(req.params) is empty.

Comment: What is your front end technology? Let me write a answer for you or you can take my help in chat section as well.

Comment: I am developing an Android app to make POST request with the id param

Comment: no idea about Android mate. I'd suggest you to read some tutorial about express routing first. The way you are receiving that route isn't correct. `'/api/updateprofile/:id'` - This is how you accept params.

Comment: Please read more on it and still if you struggle, ping me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the order of the request parameters. The "id" has to be added before the image file in order to be seen by the req.body.id.